# Text not displaying on the page after creating a textNode and appending it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a cart page and trying to show an 'empty cart' message on the page where the cart items will show. The expected behavior is to show an empty cart message in place of the cart item IF everything was deleted from the cart either using the delete button function or the minus button function. The cart item gets removed from the UI correctly when the quantity is reduced with the buttons or entirely deleted altogether with the delete button shown on each cart item. The empty cart message is not displaying at all. It could also be that the text is black like the background so it appears invisible which is why I am trying to attach and append another class "empty-cart-msg" which fixes that in the css so it's visible.

```js
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('#plus')
const minusBtn = document.querySelector('#minus')
const inputQty = document.querySelector('#inputQty')
const checkoutBtn = document.querySelector('#checkoutBtn')
const cartItem = document.querySelector('.cart')
const msg = document.querySelector('#msg')
const checkoutConfirm = document.querySelector('.checkout-confirm')
const pTag = document.querySelector('.p-tag')

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

  let qty = inputQty.value - 1

  if (inputQty.value < 2) {
    let response = setTimeout(function() {
      confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item from your cart?')
      if (response) {
        let childDiv = document.querySelector('#request-item')
        childDiv.remove()
        checkoutBtn.remove()

        // // if cart qty goes below 1, hide cart item and show empty cart msg
        cartItem.remove()

        const p = document.createElement('p')
        let msg = 'Your cart is currently empty'
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(msg)
        document.body.appendChild(p)

        p.classList.add('empty-cart-msg')
        // pTag.innerHTML += msg

      }
    }, 0)
  } else {
    inputQty.value = qty
  }
})

deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let response = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item from your cart?')

  if (response) {
    let childDiv = document.querySelector('#request-item')
    childDiv.remove()

    // remove checkout button once all cart items deleted AND show empty cart message
    checkoutBtn.remove()
    cartItem.innerHTML = 'Your cart is currently empty.'
  }
})
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <a class='back-link' href=" {% url 'supplyshop:catalog'  %}"> Back to Catalog</a>
  <h1 class='cart-h1'>Cart </h1>
  <div class='cart'>
    <p class='p-tag'></p>
    <div class='requests'>
      <div class='request' id='request-item'>
        <img class='request-img' src='https://developers.elementor.com/docs/assets/img/elementor-placeholder-image.png' alt='request image'>
        <div class='request-info'>

          <p class='request-name'>Anti-Bacterial Hand Gel (Gallon) </p>

          <div class='request-details'>
            <a href="" id='detailsLink'>Details</a>
            <p id='detailsText'>Coated palm Gloves used throughout the DC Large</p>
          </div>

          <p class='qty-text'>Qty</p>


          <div class='qty-container'>

            </br>
            <input type='button' value='+' class='qty qtyplus' id='plus' field='quantity' />
            <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' id='inputQty' />
            <input type='button' value='-' class='qty qtyminus' id='minus' field='quantity' />

            <button class='deleteBtn' id='deleteBtn' type='button'>Delete</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

I have tried to set the innerhtml = msg and tried textContent but that didn't work and after searching around it seemed like this behavior could've possibly been happening because I did not create a text node or the elements were overlapping or conflicting with each other which was another solution I tried but that doesn't work either?

Comment: I've turned your code into a snippet. Could you add the appropriate variable declarations so it will run without errors?

Comment: You're setting `response` to the timer created by `setTimeout`. You should be setting it to the result of `confirm()`. `let response = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item from your cart?')`